# Destroy last execution of activity when going resume

Tags: android

I am developing a Music Application which retrieves music files from internet.

i have two activities

1. MainActivity
2. PlayerActivity

when some one click on an element in `MainActivity` this loads the second `PlayerActivity` and a song starts playing

first time it works very well. the problem comes when some one clicks back button and clicks on another element this time song starts playing without stopping current playing song,

here is my code what i have tried .

**MainActivity**

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), PlayerActivity.class);
            EditText albumID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.albumID);
            String message = albumID.getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra(ALBUMID, message);
            startActivity(intent);
```

**PlayerActivity**

```
 try {

        if(player.isPlaying()) {
            player.release();
        }

        player.reset();
        player.setDataSource(urls.get(position));
        player.prepare();
        player.start();
        seekbar.setMax(player.getDuration());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**NOTE :**
i can post full code if needed.

Comment: So, you want to stop the playback of the song which is being played? 
And also where did you put the code of PlayerActivity (in which function)?

Comment: the code is in `onListItemClick` List item click listener. and also the MediaPlayer instance is created in class not in any method/function.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because you hold a different instance of player and thats why when you stop it it "stops" a different player than the one you want. The player is not attached to an Activity and it is not destroyed when activity is destroyed...

You should have only one instance of your player. Maybe use a singleton or a static one.
Can you stop the player when the activity is stopped? like, in it's on destroy?

If it's not clear you could try uploading more code so we could see some more..